# Flink job manager metric

Tags: apache-flink

I want to createEnumerator () method to access to Ftp file list below, and the file list for registration to the flink metric, but splitEnumeratorContext. MetricGroup () the result is null, What can I do if I cannot register with Prometheus?

```
public class FtpSourcea  implements Source<RowData, FtpSourceSplit, FtpEnumeratorCheckpoint<FtpSourceSplit>>, ParallelismProvider {
    @Override
    public Boundedness getBoundedness() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SourceReader<RowData, FtpSourceSplit> createReader(SourceReaderContext sourceReaderContext) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SplitEnumerator<FtpSourceSplit, FtpEnumeratorCheckpoint<FtpSourceSplit>> createEnumerator(SplitEnumeratorContext<FtpSourceSplit> splitEnumeratorContext) throws Exception {

        // Under this method I'm going to get the list of Ftp files that I want to report to the indicator here

        // But I splitEnumeratorContext metricGroup () is null result in my index cannot be registered to the Prometheus, how do I solve?

        // From what I know about Flink, metricGroup is only available in the task Manager, and the createEnumerator() method is executed in the Job manager


        
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SplitEnumerator<FtpSourceSplit, FtpEnumeratorCheckpoint<FtpSourceSplit>> restoreEnumerator(SplitEnumeratorContext<FtpSourceSplit> splitEnumeratorContext, FtpEnumeratorCheckpoint<FtpSourceSplit> ftpSourceSplitFtpEnumeratorCheckpoint) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleVersionedSerializer<FtpSourceSplit> getSplitSerializer() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleVersionedSerializer<FtpEnumeratorCheckpoint<FtpSourceSplit>> getEnumeratorCheckpointSerializer() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Detailed picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOzKI.png)

I tried to re-register a MetricRegistryImpl, but I couldn't get the configuration